# Footnote to forest flowchart

Tags: forest

I have been reading about this issue but am not sure about how to add a footnote to my flowchart.

I copy a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
%document class define parámetros generales para un reporte
%preambulo
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
%aca utilizo la geometría de la hoja 
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%para que funcionen bien las tildes
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url} 
\usepackage{textcomp} %para el símbolo de marca registrada
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Resume} % * avoids numeration

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
    edge+=->,
    l sep'+=10pt,
  },
  [Solvatación
    [Explícito+Implícito
      [Solvateshell + Cosmo]
      [Packmol + Cosmo]
    ]
    [Implícito
      [Cosmo]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

That script produces this image:

[image]

**I need it to have, as a footnote the next sentence** : Los bloques azules representan programas y las líneas negras scripts que los comunican.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

your `footnote` remain me on figure caption ... are you sure that it is not?

above image is produced by encapsulating `forest` image in `figure` float and using `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, headheight=18pt, headsep=18pt,
            width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm,
            bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},
            final,tracking=true,kerning=true,
            spacing=true,factor=1100,
            stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{forest}
%\pagestyle{mystyle}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Resume} % * avoids numeration

\begin{figure}[h!]
\captionsetup{skip=1ex,font=footnotesize}
\centering
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
    edge+=->,
    l sep'+=10pt,
  },
  [Solvatación
    [Explícito+Implícito
      [Solvateshell + Cosmo]
      [Packmol + Cosmo]
    ]
    [Implícito
      [Cosmo]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\caption*{Los bloques azules representan programas y las líneas negras scripts que los comunican}
\end{figure}
```

*note:* with deleting * at `caption` you can transform this footnote to real caption.