# Beamer flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I was wondering if someone could show me how to make this flow chart for a beamer presentation?

[image]

Comment: With `forest` is simple. Show us, what you try so far and where you stuck.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388098/footnote-to-forest-flowchart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As starting point:

- In question you emphasize, that flowchart should be in `beamer` but you not provide any information about its style, more over in your question you not use it at all.
- Proposed flowchart is just a skeleton, real text in nodes I left you to write
- Temporary nodes border are not visible (since they are white) because used theme is unknown and consequently left that you added it.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names]{beamer}
% used theme is unknown
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    draw=white, thick, rounded corners,
    fill=SteelBlue1,
    font=\small\bfseries\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
    text=white,
    minimum height=12mm,
    text width=5em,
    text centered,
% tree
    grow=east,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    calign=edge midpoint,
    edge = {color=SteelBlue1},
    l sep=6mm,
    s sep=1mm
            }
[root two lines text
    [child A
        [text   [text]]
        [text text text [very long text in three lines]]
        [text   [text]]
    ]
    [child B
        [text   [text]]
        [text text text  [text]]
        [text   [text]]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

- Considered is document preamble, which is provided in  comment below (if you not like X11names, you can select any others; however, accordingly you should change names of colors used in `forest`)
- It may be one step closer to image showed in question:

  - flowchart is inserted into `beamercolorbox`, so now white nodes borders are wisible;
  - To say frankly, I disliked such solution. I would rather change nodes border for example to `SteelBlue3` and remove
    `beamercolorbox`

```
\documentclass[[aspectratio=169,xcolor=x11names]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercolor{forest}{fg=white,bg=blue}
 
\usepackage{multirow} 
%\usepackage{graphicx} %   it is loaded by beamer
\usepackage{booktabs} 
%\usepackage{amsmath} %   it is loaded by beamer
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
\usepackage{forest} 
% \usepackage{hyperref} %   it is loaded by beamer

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
    \centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em,wd=\linewidth]{forest}
    \begin{forest}
% flowchart code
    \end{forest}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so very much @Zarko

Comment: @zarko....have some error and here is: \documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{forest}
\title[]{} 
\subtitle{}

\author[] {\textbf{}}

\institute[] 
{\textbf{XXXXX} \\
 \textbf{XXXX}
}
\date{\textbf{}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{forest}

    \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Comment: @Tullu05, you change color names from `x11names` to `xcolor=dvipsnames`. Using last you need to change color name in forest options accordingly. Theme Madrid doesn't gives dark blue background. This comment you should add to question.

Comment: I sill get this error @Zarko : File `forest.sty' not found.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Tullu05, than you need to upload to your LaTeX installation. Sorry, I can't see, what you doing, how id your LaTeX installed, etc. BTW, using Overleaf online service, my MWE works fine.